# How to get lynx to recognize whitespace in filenames

Tags: lynx

I'm using a script to find a list of all .pdf files on a url. But lynx seems to have a problem with spaces in filenames. Here's the script:

```
lynx --dump http://www.somesite/here/ | awk '/http/{print $2} | grep pdf > ~/Desktop/links.txt
```

This works as expected until there is a .pdf with whitespace in the filename. Lynx seems to truncate the filename at the whitespace. Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: Would be surprising. Do you have a sample or two?

Comment: are you *sure* that it's Lynx that is truncating the filename? Could you provide a sample from that `lynx --dump` that demonstrates the filename? I think, rather, that you're seeing `awk` print only one field of a white-space delimited line (once you get past the missing closing quote).

Comment: When I do it, it creates the file links.txt but it is blank.

Comment: Could you edit into the question the lynx-dump output piped through `grep http`?

Comment: ok, so this works fine: ``lynx -dump http://somesite | grep pdf > ~/Desktop/links.txt``

Comment: Do you have a ~/.lynxrc file that is setting the `-source` option "for" you? I can repro with `lynx -dump -source ...` but not with `lynx -dump ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk (by default) uses blanks as field-separators, and lynx is rendering a blank in a dumped url as a blank.  Work around it as I suggested in a bug report:

```
lynx -listonly -dump http://www.somesite/here/ | \
awk '/\.pdf$/{ sub("^[ ]*[0-9]+.[ ]*","",$0); print}' > ~/Desktop/links.txt
```

If the content happens to be in UTF-8 encoding, lynx *unescapes* the text (undoes URL-encoding such as **`%20`**), showing a blank in this case (making that two or more fields for awk, depending on the number of blanks in the name).

That unescaping was done for Debian [#398274](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=398274), in 2013 (i.e., you've got that feature with Ubuntu 18.04).

Adding the **`-listonly`** option reduces the number of incorrect matches, by looking only at the *list* of URLs.

If you wanted to look for multiple file-types, you could list the suffixes as alternatives in the regular expression, e.g., something like this:

```
awk '/\.(pdf|odt|doc|docx)$/{ sub("^[ ]*[0-9]+.[ ]*","",$0); print}' > ~/Desktop/links.txt
```

Comment: This does fix my issue; thank you. One question: If I wanted to use awk to read for multiple file types (.pdf, .odt, .doc, docx), how would I alter this code?